# desktopCapture in Chrome - cancelChooseDesktopMedia results in Crash

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, screensharing

I'm playing around with Screensharing in Webrtc and ran into the following issue:

I want to hide the media picker dialog (see below) when clicking a button (screenshot Cancel text).

[image: media picker dialog]

According to [the documentation:](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture)

```
cancelChooseDesktopMedia(integer desktopMediaRequestId)
Hides (the) desktop media picker dialog shown by chooseDesktopMedia().
Id returned by chooseDesktopMedia()
```

*sounds exactly like what I want*

#### in my background.js

(I'm writing an [extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) to avoid setting the allow capture flag in `chrome://flags` by hand)

I get the `desktopMediaRequestId` like this:

```
var desktopMediaRequestId = '';
desktopMediaRequestId = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(data_sources, port.sender.tab, function(streamId){ ... });
```

and call `cancelChooseDesktopMedia` it like that:

```
if (desktopMediaRequestId)
    chrome.desktopCapture.cancelChooseDesktopMedia(desktopMediaRequestId);
```

However,

- Chrome (Version 34.0.1847.131)
- and Canary (Version 36.0.1964.2 canary)

**freeze and crash** with the Dialog still open after `cancelChooseDesktopMedia` is called.

I posted the most relevant stuff for now. Just scream and I will provide more information :).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are open chrome bugs about [crashing](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=cancelChooseDesktopMedia&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=384892) or the desktop picker simply [not closing](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=383999&q=cancelChooseDesktopMedia&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified#makechanges) on macs